# Java LongCache returns wrong value

Tags: java, jvm, autoboxing

Long variables in my online application get wrong value after runing sometime.
I found this happens when my code autoboxing primitive long value to Long object implicitly.
I know that for long value -127 to 128 java returns cached Long objects when program returns primitive long numbers.
After some debugging, I see LongCache saves wrong value for some index. In my screenshot you can see that cache index 128 stores value 38 which should be 0; index 165 stores 38 which should be 37.
From source code, LongCache is populated in static block during bootstrap. And there is no getter setter to update this cache. I can't think of a way how this could happen.
The LongCache values become correct after restarting application.
Has anyone ever encountered this issue? Thanks.
My program is in Java 11.

[128 index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3jNO.png)

[165 index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCCLv.png)

Comment: There are numerous examples on this site and in the web, showing how this cache could be manipulated via Reflection. There are even speculations about how a jester or rage quitting developer could make the other developers’ life harder with such a prank.

Comment: Thanks @Holger, you point me to the right direction of search. This answer does remind me a line of code in my application that alter Long value through reflection.